# MATLAB, ols function not working from an Econometrics toolbox

Tags: matlab

I am trying to run a simple OLS regression,

```
    %Demonstrate regression using the ols() function

    %Step 1. Load the data
    clear;
    clc;

    y=[1 2 3 4 5]
    x=[1 2 3 4 5]

    result=ols(y,x);
    prt(result);
    prt(result);

I am using James LeSages econometric tool box and the OLS function is here, 

function results=ols(y,x)
% PURPOSE: least-squares regression 
%---------------------------------------------------
% USAGE: results = ols(y,x)
% where: y = dependent variable vector    (nobs x 1)
%        x = independent variables matrix (nobs x nvar)
%---------------------------------------------------
% RETURNS: a structure
%        results.meth  = 'ols'
%        results.beta  = bhat     (nvar x 1)
%        results.tstat = t-stats  (nvar x 1)
%        results.bstd  = std deviations for bhat (nvar x 1)
%        results.yhat  = yhat     (nobs x 1)
%        results.resid = residuals (nobs x 1)
%        results.sige  = e'*e/(n-k)   scalar
%        results.rsqr  = rsquared     scalar
%        results.rbar  = rbar-squared scalar
%        results.dw    = Durbin-Watson Statistic
%        results.nobs  = nobs
%        results.nvar  = nvars
%        results.y     = y data vector (nobs x 1)
%        results.bint  = (nvar x2 ) vector with 95% confidence intervals on beta
%---------------------------------------------------
% SEE ALSO: prt(results), plt(results)
%---------------------------------------------------

% written by:
% James P. LeSage, Dept of Economics
% University of Toledo
% 2801 W. Bancroft St,
% Toledo, OH 43606
% jlesage@spatial-econometrics.com
%
% Barry Dillon (CICG Equity)
% added the 95% confidence intervals on bhat

if (nargin ~= 2); error('Wrong # of arguments to ols'); 
else
 [nobs nvar] = size(x); [nobs2 junk] = size(y);
 if (nobs ~= nobs2); error('x and y must have same # obs in ols'); 
 end;
end;

results.meth = 'ols';
results.y = y;
results.nobs = nobs;
results.nvar = nvar;

if nobs < 10000
  [q r] = qr(x,0);
  xpxi = (r'*r)\eye(nvar);
else % use Cholesky for very large problems
  xpxi = (x'*x)\eye(nvar);
end;

results.beta = xpxi*(x'*y);
results.yhat = x*results.beta;
results.resid = y - results.yhat;
sigu = results.resid'*results.resid;
results.sige = sigu/(nobs-nvar);
tmp = (results.sige)*(diag(xpxi));
sigb=sqrt(tmp);
results.bstd = sigb;
tcrit=-tdis_inv(.025,nobs);
results.bint=[results.beta-tcrit.*sigb, results.beta+tcrit.*sigb];
results.tstat = results.beta./(sqrt(tmp));
ym = y - mean(y);
rsqr1 = sigu;
rsqr2 = ym'*ym;
results.rsqr = 1.0 - rsqr1/rsqr2; % r-squared
rsqr1 = rsqr1/(nobs-nvar);
rsqr2 = rsqr2/(nobs-1.0);
if rsqr2 ~= 0
results.rbar = 1 - (rsqr1/rsqr2); % rbar-squared
else
    results.rbar = results.rsqr;
end;
ediff = results.resid(2:nobs) - results.resid(1:nobs-1);
results.dw = (ediff'*ediff)/sigu; % durbin-watson
```

I get an error when I try to run this.

I get an error in line 64.

Is this an obvious fix? The function would be really useful and hopefully, someone can help.

https://www.spatial-econometrics.com/

Here is the econometrics tool box.

So my top code is calling for the ols function.

I think this is due to not having all the relevant functions in the same MATLAB folder, does this make a difference?

Comment: This is probably the third time you're asking this question. Another one is this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51705348/

Comment: Yes, thanks Sardar, now I have found a how to write an example properly (hopefully), I got some help with it.

Comment: Its also the second, and I'm really sorry, but I would like some help if possible.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted code that runs, this does, last time I made a mistake defining the x and y

Comment: I delted the other one. Sorry about that. We can run with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing a few dependencies. Your ols file looks like the one in this matlab-central contribution: https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45093-time-frequency-generalized-phase-synchrony-for-eeg-signal-analysis

It even states in it's description the same source than the one you provided. And it contains all required dependencies. Maybe too much for your usecase...